# How do I correctly import an animation from blender into UE4?

Tags: blender, unreal-4

I have animated a conveyor belt in blender. When I import the animation to UE4, the conveyor belt does not move correctly. What am I doing wrong?
Here is a link to my blender file: [Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rbnvguupuhdm92/2.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Are you tried to export as .fbx file? It's usually more compatible. And can you show what is wrong

Comment: "does not move correctly" - explain what that means, please. Does it not move at all? Or is something about the movement wrong?

Comment: I have been exporting as .fbx and UE4 is not display my animation correctly. So, I have an object with a clone modifier and a curve modifier. The object clones itself for the length of a bezier circle and it curves around the bezier to form a conveyor belt. In blender, when the object is moved along the x-axis, it follows the curve and moves like a conveyor belt. In UE4, the entire conveyor belt shape moves along the x-axis without the object following the curve.